# Automatically separate and delimit a string in Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google sheets has an option which is selectable from the top menu to separate text into columns when specifying a character. It's possible use a comma or other characters.

I am looking for a script which can do this process automatically for a given column. There are numerous scripts available to do this but I have not been able to accomplish my task using them.

I am using an application on Android which allows me to scan a qr code and send the string of information to Google sheets.

A sample of the information would appear as : 464839|362|2840|927|72|617

I need to separate this information into separate columns when the information is sent to sheets. The process should be automatic.

I have a snip of code which I've found searching however it doesn't work for me.

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var cell = range.getCell(1, 1); // Gets the cell A1 
var cellValue = cell.getValue(); // Gets the value of the cell A1

var cellArray = cellValue.split("|"); // Splits the cell value by ',' and  stores it in array.

//Iterate through the array
for(var i = 0; i < cellArray.length; i++){
    Logger.log(cellArray[i]);
}
```

I'm not very code savvy, please help.

Comment: Where in the sheet is the sample data outputted and what row do you want the data to be split along?

Comment: I'd like the data to be out put across the row its put in. When ever I scan a qr code, the app puts the data in column 1 it uses each available next space each time. , id like the data to grow horizontal. The sample data doesn't need to be retained. The only important part is that the data is  extracted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Below would be a code that you place on an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that runs at a regular interval and iterates through the values of each row in column A and tries to split the value with the pipe symbol and the replace then write those split values along the columns in that row. If this has already been done in the past the function will error when it tries to split the values because no pipe symbol exists but the try/catch will catch that error and allow the function to continue through the loop.

```
    function myFunction() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NameOFSheet"); //Change "NameOFSheet to the actual name of the sheet.
      var col1Values = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1) //Gets 2d (2 dimensional) array of the Values in Column 1 (getSheetValues(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns)_
      var splitVals = []; //Instantiate an empty 1d array variable
      //Iterate through the 2d array and set the values
      for(var i = 0; i < col1Values.length; i++){
        try{
          splitVals = col1Values[i][0].split("|"); //Creates a 1d array of values split at every occurrence of the pipe symbol ("|").
          //If there is no pipe symbol (which would be the case if this operation has already happened then the array will be blank because .split will throw an error which will get "caught" in the try catch and the row will be skipped

          //Iterate over the splitVals array and set the values of the columns along the row (i+1) that you are in.
          for(var col = 0; col < splitVals.length; col++){
            sheet.getRange(i+1, col+1).setValue(splitVals[col])
          }
        }catch(e){}

      }
    }
```

I commented the code for explanation. I would recommend reading up on [2 dimensional arrays](http://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-multidimensional-array/) to help you understand them and the code above better.